# How to call js function in php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a problem when i want to call js function, the chart is not show up, i dont know how to call js function because i need to show my chart

js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
    var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: $labelChart2, //Jamnya
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(232,72,163,0.2)',
                borderColor: '#e848a3',
                label: $dtDateChart2,
                data: $totalChart2,
                fill: true,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
                showLine: true
            }]
        }, options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Total Online Yesterday',
                position: 'top',
                fontSize: 15,
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    pointStyle: 'circle'
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'TIME'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        major: {
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fontColor: '#FF0000'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips:{
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      return '$dtDateChart2 '+data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      return 'TOTAL : '+data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']]+'';
                    },
                },
                titleFontSize: 15,
                bodyFontSize: 15,
                displayColors: false
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

my php

```
<canvas id="myChart2" class="canpas chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 454px; height: 300px;" width="454" height="300"></canvas>';
```

anyoone have ever meet with this problem ? when i put in global boddy. the function is call for global and always show value that i define null in other class except class for chart

Comment: Do you get any error message in console?

Comment: if i put the script on the top of my php.. when i alert anything. it shw up. but if the functin like above . not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in the following line:

```
data: $totalChart2,
```

If $totalChart2 is a php variable, js will not be able to read it.

If your js function is in a php file, you will have to use the following at the least:

```
data: <?php echo $totalChart2 ?>,
```

Also make sure the echo command prints a valid js array or object.

Comment: and how to call the js function? inside my cansa or ?

Comment: What js function? If you just want the chart, the code in your <script> tag is fine. As long as you have the var myChart2 = new Chart(.....) part correct, the chart will should up.

Comment: bro, when i define this -> `var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');`

and the bottom of that code i use alert('asd');

the alert is not working but if i erase document.getelement bla bla. the alert is working.

and the mistake in document.getelement

Comment: i al;ready fixed it,. but i cant shwo the value, i already use <?php echo